# How to make flex items of different size to fill parent when wrapped

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following template:

```
<div id="row">
  <div id="longer"></div>
  <div id="shorter"></div>
</div>
```

When they are in the same row, i would like `longer` to take twice as much width as `shorter`, so I've applied the following CSS:

```
#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#longer {
  flex: 1 0;
}

#shorter {
  flex: 0.5 0;
}
```

This seemingly works fine, but when `shorter` is wrapped, it takes only 50% of the new row, even though it's the only item in that row.

I would like `shorter` to fill the entire row, if it's the only item in that line.

Is this possible to achieve without media queries?

[**Plunker link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oRsDfXr0hefSNI9ct4X5?p=preview)

Comment: You may want to read up on how flex grow works https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/ as it doesn't split the space between the items, it uses the remaining space instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases where the sum of children's `flex-grow` value is less than 1, they will not fill the entire parent's width, and only the corresponding fraction instead.

You can just multiply them up by the same scale so they are at least 1:

```css
#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#longer {
  flex: 2 0;
}

#shorter {
  flex: 1 0;
}


/* Just for demo */

#row div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#row div:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}

#row div:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <div id="longer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  <div id="shorter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it `flex: 2 0` and `flex: 1 0` - fractional `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` will only *flex* a *fraction* of the available space in the *flex axis*. See demo below:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

#row {
  flex: 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#longer {
  flex: 2 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#shorter {
  flex: 1 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <div id="longer">
    this_is_the_longer_div_asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
  </div>
  <div id="shorter">
    this_should_fill_parent_width_when_wrapped
  </div>
</div>
```